I want to add pip mode in flutter for IOS
I added pip mode in flutter it is working for android well but I need it for IOS. Anyone help me please.
I used simple pip mode package also but is not worked for me. I need it same like whatsapp video call pip mode I am playing video in my flutter app.
I need better solutions from the experts

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Hello did you succed?
Can you help how did you achieve?
Video call through PIP

Try to use some other package like fl_pip package https://pub.dev/packages/fl_pip
